# Why does this empty synchronized block affect the output of the program?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, output, synchronized

So I was just messing around with basic concurrency when I noticed the empty synchronized block shown in the program causes the outputs to sync up. There is nothing in the block, so why does it do this?

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SyncTest f = new SyncTest();
        f.start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            System.out.println("MAIN THREAD:" + i);
            Thread.sleep(500);
               synchronized (f) {
                for (int t = 0; t < 15; t++) {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

---

```
class SyncTest extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            try {
                System.out.println("OTHER THREAD: " + i);
                Thread.sleep(1300);
                synchronized (this) {} //Why does this have an effect on the output when commented?
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The purpose of the `synchronized` command is to sync up between threads. Why would you expect it to have no effect, just because it doesn't contain any code?

Comment: What do you mean `causes the outputs to sync up`

Comment: Copy and paste the code yourselves and you can see what happens with the output with the existence of the block and without it.

Answer (score 1):

The execution flow will not enter a `synchronized` block if the specified lock has already been taken by another thread. This is *always* the case, even if the synchronized block contains no code at all.

The locks in your example are the same object (the instance of `SyncTest`.) So while the non-empty synchronized block is running, the empty one will be waiting for it to complete. In this case, because of the way the `Thread.sleep()` calls line up, it just so happens that the outputs are reasonably likely to be synchronized as a result.

Answer (score 1):

The mechanics of the synchronized can be summed up like this

```
synchronized(f) { //wait for no-one use f
    // do some stuff
    //nobdy can use f during this time
} //free f, other can use it
```

It basically act like if you used a lock, where the lock is f

So even if your block does nothing than waiting, during this wait time f is not available. So it will synchronize your program even if there's only a wait in your block

Answer (score 0):

You've got synchronized 2 times by the same object.

First time in the MainClass:

```
SyncTest f = new SyncTest();
synchronized (f) {...}
```

Second time in the SyncTest instance itself by "this":

```
synchronized (this) {}
```

There are 2 threads in your program: main thread and thread of SyncTest.
Each thread comes to the point of synchronization by SyncTest object and waits until another thread will go out of the synchronization section.

Answer (score 0):

[Berry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50045089/7653073) summarizes what `synchronized` does and mentions that the content of the block does not matter. So the question is not really **why** the behavior changes, but why it changes so drasticly.

Your threads "sync up" (i.e. log one by one even though `otherThread` should be a bit faster and sometimes log twice before `mainThread`) because your **`mainThread` sleeps for a solid 1500ms** when blocking the sync object:

```
synchronized (f)
{
    for (int t = 0; t < 15; t++)  // this is
    {                             // (roughly)
        Thread.sleep(100);        // equivalent to 
    }                             // Thread.sleep(1500);
}
```

That means that `mainThread` doesn't give `otherThread` a chance use its speed advantage (1300 ms vs. 1500ms) and makes it wait until it is done sleeping. Change that piece of code to

```
for (int t = 0; t < 15; t++)
{
    synchronized (f)
    {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
}
```

and  `otherThread` will slide right into one of those breaks between the 100ms naps and the empty sync block is not affecting anything much anymore.

**Note** that the empty sync block still has a little effect and might change the order of the logs a bit because `otherThread` might still have to wait a little (but only a maximum 100ms instead of 1500ms). It won't result in such a strict back-and-fourth anymore, though.